# Joint Moments of Stochastic Process at Different Times

Tags: probability-or-statistics, symbolic, random-process

Suppose I have a random process defined in Mathematica, e.g.

```
h = TelegraphProcess[a]
```

I know you can use Mathematica to calculate different statistics like the mean, autocovariance, etc. like this

```
CovarianceFunction[h, s, t] (*gives -E^(-2 a (s + t)) + E^(-2 a Abs[-s + t])*)
```

I was wondering if there's a way to find general higher order joint moments of the process at different times. E.g. something like
$$\mathbb{E}\left[h(t_1)h(t_2)h(t_3)h(t_4)\right]$$

Does Mathematica have the capability to find these things symbolically (at least in principle)? Or are we limited to the built-in functions like `Mean`, `Variance`, etc.

Comment: Do you mean something like `Clear[h]; Expectation[h[t1] h[t2] h[t3] h[t4], h \[Distributed] TelegraphProcess[a]]` ?

Comment: @Domen Yes! I didn't know you could do that. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`Expectation`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Expectation.html):

```
Expectation[h[t1] h[t2] h[t3] h[t4], h \[Distributed] TelegraphProcess[a]]
(* ConditionalExpression[E^(2 a t1 - 2 a t2 + 2 a t3 - 2 a t4), t1 < t2 < t3 < t4] *)
```